# wait not working in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, multiprocessing

I am running a for loop in which a command is run in background using &. In the end i want all commands to return value..

Here is the code i tried

```
for((i=0 ;i<3;i++)) {

    // curl command which returns a value   & 
    } 
    wait
```

// next piece of code

I want to get all three returned value and then proceed.. But the wait command does not wait for background processes to complete and runs the next part of code.  I need the returned values to proceed..

Comment: Can you give an example of the `curl` URL you're trying to request against? Your code looks legit, though there might be some special character in your URL that prevents it from working. One option might be to put your URLs in double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Shell builtins have documentation accessible with `help BUILTIN_NAME`.
`help wait` yields:

```
wait: wait [-n] [id ...]
    Wait for job completion and return exit status.

    Waits for each process identified by an ID, which may be a process ID or a
    job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
    given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
    status is zero.  If ID is a a job specification, waits for all processes
    in that job's pipeline.

    If the -n option is supplied, waits for the next job to terminate and
    returns its exit status.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid
    option is given.
```

which implies that to get the return statuses, you need to save the pid and then wait on each pid, using `wait $THE_PID`.

Example:

```
sl() { sleep $1; echo $1; return $(($1+42));  }
pids=(); for((i=0;i<3;i++)); do sl $i & pids+=($!); done; 
for pid in ${pids[@]}; do wait $pid; echo ret=$?; done
```

Example output:

```
0
ret=42
1
ret=43
2
ret=44
```

**Edit**:

With curl, don't forget to pass `-f` (`--fail`) to make sure the process will fail if the HTTP request did:

CURL Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
URIs=(
    https://pastebin.com/raw/w36QWU3D 
    https://pastebin.com/raw/NONEXISTENT
    https://pastebin.com/raw/M9znaBB2
     )

pids=(); for((i=0;i<3;i++)); do
    curl -fL "${URIs[$i]}" &>/dev/null &
    pids+=($!)

done
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    wait $pid
    echo ret=$?
done
```

CURL Example output:

```
ret=0
ret=22
ret=0
```

Comment: Modified my code accordingly... Still not working.. Can you look into it

for((i=0 ;i<3;i++)) { // curl command which returns a value & pids+=($! }
 done

for pid in ${pids[@] } ;do
wait $pid
done

Comment: @user8147819 Added a curl example.

Comment: For some reason, background jobs don't seem to start in scripts like they do in an interactive shell. Put a `jobs` statement in your script after starting the curl commands as background jobs, you'll notice it doesn't output anything. Also put `pstree -p <your shell's PID>` and `ps -F` after jobs, you'll notice that the PIDs of the curl commands aren't child processes to the script's shell. I don't know why.

Comment: @user625488 In an interactive shell, you should get a separate process group per backgrounded job. In a noninteractive shell (a script), the backgrounded jobs should be just children of the scripts pid, with no dedicated process group. Anyway, I can't confirm your results: https://pastebin.com/FeiLbiuZ (I'm getting both the expected output for jobs, and the curl procs being shown as children of the script).

Comment: @PSkocik Right. I wanted to delete my comment, but wasn't fast enough :-) I wasn't using a script, just a command line: `(((./sh1.sh 11 124; echo $? > SH1_RESULT ) & ); ((./sh2.sh 9 125; echo $? > SH2_RESULT ) & ); while true; do echo "Jobs follow."; jobs; pstree -p $$; ps -F; SH1_RESULT=$(<SH1_RESULT); SH2_RESULT=$(<SH2_RESULT); if [ -n "$SH1_RESULT"  ] && [ -n "$SH2_RESULT" ]; then echo 'exit 1'; break; else echo "still looping"; fi; sleep 2; echo ""; done; rm -f SH*;)`. The `sh{n}.sh` scripts `sleep $1` then `exit $2`. What I saw was due to subshells ending before `sh{n}.sh`.

Answer (score -1):

**GNU Parallel** is a great way to do high-latency things like `curl` in parallel.

```
parallel curl --head {} ::: www.google.com www.hp.com www.ibm.com
```

Or, filtering results:

```
parallel curl --head -s {} ::: www.google.com www.hp.com www.ibm.com | grep '^HTTP'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

Here is another example:

```
parallel -k 'echo -n Starting {} ...; sleep 5; echo done.'  ::: 1 2 3 4
Starting 1 ...done.
Starting 2 ...done.
Starting 3 ...done.
Starting 4 ...done.
```

Comment: Can you please give an example

Comment: That is an example, it uses `curl` to download the headers from the 3 sites listed after the `:::` all in parallel. Try `parallel -k echo {} ::: 1 2 5 6`